# How to release the focus of QPushButton which is the default button of the QDialog?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QDialog which has a QPushButton and a QLineEdit. QPushButton is set as the default button. When I run the dialog and click Enter key, QPushButton is clicked and corresponding slot is invoked, which is the expected behavior. But when I click on the QLineEdit using mouse and then click Enter key again, also invoke the QPushButton's clicked slot. How to prevent this? I want to click Enter button on other widgets to do nothing. When I use the Tab key to navigate through widgets, QPushButton's is always bold (highlighted) which I guess the reason why it is invoked every time Enter key is pressed.

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the AutoDefault value of the Button to false.

```
void setAutoDefault(bool)
```

see: [Qt-Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#autoDefault-prop)

If there are more Buttons in your dialog you also have to set their autoDefault value to false. Otherwise these buttons will get focus and be executed on enter pressed.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't (directly) depend on focus: when a widget doesn't handle an event, it is forwarded to the widget's parent. QLineEdit doesn't handle enter, so it sends it to the QDialog, which activates the default button on enter. The default button is displayed in a special way, e.g. a bold border on your style .

You could write your own QLineEdit subclass that prevents the Enter-event from propagating:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class MyLineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
public:
    MyLineEdit(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QLineEdit(parent) {}

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
        if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Return) {
            event->accept(); // I have handled the event, don't propagate
        } else {
            QLineEdit::keyPressEvent(event);
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QDialog d;
    QLineEdit *l = new MyLineEdit(&d);
    QPushButton *b = new QPushButton("Ok", &d);
    b->setDefault(true);
    QHBoxLayout *h = new QHBoxLayout(&d);
    h->addWidget(l, 1);
    h->addWidget(b);

    QObject::connect(b, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]{QMessageBox::information(&d, "OK", "OK");});

    d.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: If I use this method, I will have to create my own classes for every widget inside QDialog except QPushButton. Because I want every other widget to ignore Enter key press. What I did was, I used the keyPressEvent on QDialog to ignore Enter key press. It ignores Enter key press on every widget inside QDialog including QPushButton. But since I have written the slot for QPushButtons clicked signal, Enter key press on QPushButton invoked that slot. That was exactly what I wanted. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: That sounds like you don't want default button behaviour. Just as an aside: you could have also used an event filter instead of subclassing everything: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter